# MYSQL How to get the start and end date of a week?

Tags: mysql, dayofweek

After I do query, I already got the year, month, and week after grouping them using YEAR(),MONTH() and WEEK() functions. But, I lost somewhere to display the start date and end date from the query.

| delivery_date | isActive |
| --- | --- |
| 18/1/2021 | 1 |
| 19/1/2021 | 1 |
| 20/1/2021 | 1 |

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(delivery_date), ' / ', MONTH(delivery_date), ' / ', WEEK(delivery_date)) AS WEEK
  FROM ode_orders 
 WHERE isActive = 1 
 GROUP 
    BY WEEK
```

The result of the group and concatenation

```
2021 / 1 / 3
```

How to display its start and end date of the week?

Like for example this table below?

| year / month / week | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 / 1 / 3 | 18/1/2021 | 20/1/2021 |

Comment: You also need to confirm what you consider to be the first day of the first week of the year

Comment: And a three day week seems like a strange thing

Comment: Sorry my example is not clear. I just want to show the date it's taken from the data that merged into the weeks. I know a week have 7 days and suppose to display between first and 7th day. But if the data only have three days from the week, then I want it to show that 3 days only. The example data below is just small part from my whole table. Appreciate if you can help =)

Comment: I feel like I've explained what I think you need to do. If you choose not to take those steps, that's fine, but I cannot help further in that case.

Answer (score 0):

> How to get the start and end date of a week?

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(@year, '-01-01') + INTERVAL @week WEEK - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CONCAT(@year, '-01-01')) DAY as first_day_of_week,
       CONCAT(@year, '-01-01') + INTERVAL @week WEEK - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CONCAT(@year, '-01-01')) - 6 DAY as last_day_of_week;
```

`@month` source data is excess, the week is fully determined by the year and week number.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4dd414a3e50852111b2fa0edf2766629)